# Proving that $\Vert Ax\Vert \leq \Vert A\Vert \Vert x\Vert$ where $A$ is a matrix and $x$ a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, solution-verification, vectors

I would like to prove that $\Vert Ax\Vert \leq \Vert A\Vert \Vert x\Vert$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$-matrix and $x = \left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
\vdots\\
x_n\end{array}\right)$ is a vector. I've tried a proof below, in which I used the following definitions:

- The norm of a matrix $A$ is $\Vert A\Vert := \max\limits_{j=1,...,n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|A_{ij}|$
- The norm of a vector $x$ is $\Vert x\Vert := \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|$

With this my reasoning was:

Take a vector $x \ne \left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\vdots\\
0\end{array}\right)$, then we can write:

$$\Vert A\Vert = \left\Vert\frac{Ax}{x}\right\Vert = \frac{\Vert Ax\Vert}{\Vert x\Vert} = \frac{\max\limits_{j=1,...,n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|A_{ij}x_i|}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}$$

But then I introduce a vector $y = \left(\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\
\vdots\\
y_n\end{array}\right) \ne \left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\vdots\\
0\end{array}\right)$ such that:

$$\Vert A\Vert = \frac{\max\limits_{j=1,...,n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|A_{ij}x_i|}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i} \geq \frac{\max\limits_{j=1,...,n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|A_{ij}y_i|}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_i} = \frac{\Vert Ay\Vert}{\Vert y\Vert}$$

And multiplying both sides $\Vert y\Vert$ I thus get the required inequality:

$$\Vert Ay\Vert \leq \Vert A\Vert\Vert y\Vert$$ i.e $$\Vert Ax\Vert \leq \Vert A\Vert\Vert x\Vert$$

Is it correct ? The part I have doubts concerns the existence of such $y$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do you define $\frac{Ax}{x}$? There is not usually a well defined 'division by vector'.

Comment: Well that is true but in this case I just introduce it with multiplication by $1$, I didn't think it we would need definition of $\frac{Ax}{x}$ to do that

Comment: How do you mean 'multiplication by 1'? The term $\frac{x}{x}$ has the same problem.

Comment: Well I thought that no matter the definition of $\frac{x}{x}$, we can use the fact that $\frac{x}{x} = 1$

Comment: The fact that an object divided by itself is equal to 1 is only true in the cases where you have a well defined division, which is not the case for vectors.

Comment: Yeah I understood that from your second comment but I wanted to check, so thank you !

Comment: For a double stroked vertical bar use `\Vert`.

Comment: Didn't know that either, thanks !

Comment: Indeed as well @Masacroso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explicit computation that proves your claim. For any vector $x$ we get

$$\Vert Ax\Vert = \left\Vert\left(\sum_j a_{1j}x_j,\dots,\sum_j a_{nj}x_j \right)\right\Vert = \sum_i \left|\sum_j a_{ij} x_j\right| \leq \sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}x_j| = \sum_j \underbrace{\left(\sum_i|a_{ij}|\right)}_{\leq \max_j \sum_i |a_{ij}|}|x_j| \leq \left(\max_j \sum_i |a_{ij}|\right) \cdot \sum_j |x_j| = \Vert A\Vert \Vert x\Vert.$$

Comment: That is indeed a very interesting alternative to this problem ! Thanks a lot @S.Farr

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the existence of $y$. But here I can give you alternate proof using contradiction.

Suppose $\Vert Ax \Vert > \Vert A \Vert \Vert x \Vert$. Then we can obtain,

$$\frac{\Vert Ax \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} > \Vert A\Vert.$$
As a result, $\Big \Vert A \frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert} \Big \Vert > \Vert A \Vert$.

But the vector $\frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert}$ is unit norm. Thus, this contradicts the definition of A-norm.

Comment: That is very nice of you, but I should have stated that I had already done this exercice as a homework, and actually I solved it with your exact method, but then I didn't get the full grade because I was told that the contradiction you states does not actually contradicts the definition of matrix given at the beginning of my post. So do you understand why ?